# Chrome extension: writing content into a dynamic iframe created in a sandboxed environment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

I can't overcome this issue. Can someone give some advice?

1. I have this application that uses ExtJS library that I will need to run in Chrome extension. I have successfully created my messaging bridge (`postMessage`), and sandboxed the whole application in it, and everything works as usual. ExtJS loaded, application is running.
2. Then I have this piece of logic where I need to preview a piece of HTML snippets in my ExtJS viewport. I created an `iframe` in the `Panel` itself and on `afterrender` I tried to write the snippet in it. This is the code I use:

   ```
   html: '<iframe src="about:blank" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;"></iframe>';

   ......

   //p is the panel found in afterrender
   p.body.down('iframe').dom.contentDocument.write(content);
   ```

   Then the error:

   > Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL about:blank from frame with URL chrome-extension://fcnpmlgapilgclcelfanblpbglmkghbc/core/themes/default/app.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
3. <strike>I have tried with `postMessage` within sandbox to this dynamic iframe but nothing happens. Setting the `sandbox` attribute in manifest doesn't work either.</strike> This is the only way and it works. See my answer below.

**Question:**

1. How should one set the manifest to support this kind of use case?
2. Or is there any better way to preview HTML snippet without using an `iframe`? Afaik previewing with `iframe` is the best as it sandboxed the snippet without being messed with parent css.

**Note**

This piece of code was working fine in manifest v1 but I planned to migrate it to manifest v2. I didn't realize Content Security Policy (CSP) has became that strict.

A screen to describe the problem ;)

[image: screen]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, this is awkward. Apparently `postMessage` is the only way, and I can't manage to get it work previously because my iframe is not loaded yet. Also, accessing the dom document in the iframe is a big *no* under CSP, but it's possible to access `contentWindow` to do a `postMessage`.

This is what I did to solve this issue. Hope someone would benefit from this:

1. Create a `preview.html` in your extension root
2. Under `manifest.json`, add it as part of the [`sandbox`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html#sandbox) attribute
3. Inside the `preview.html`, add the following code. Note that my snippet is a full html, so I used `document.write` instead.

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
       <head>
           <script>
           window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
               if (e.data.content) {
                   document.write(e.data.content);
               }
           });
           </script>
       </head>
       <body></body>
   </html>
   ```
4. Create the iframe in your code as usual, point it to your `preview.html`, and attach it to the parent div or `Ext.Panel`.
5. Use the following code to `postMessage` after the element has been drawn/created/appended.

   ```
   var content = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hello World!</body></html>';
   var iframe = p.body.down('iframe').dom; //or the iframe node

   iframe.onload = function() {
       iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({content: content}, '*');
   };
   ```

Enjoy ;)

**Edit**

As pointed by [Mike in Chromium forum](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/969VmAxPJvk/3wJFREN4cNEJ), this issue can be solved by [`srcdoc`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-srcdoc) as well. Simply set the iframe's srcdoc and problem is solved.

Just not sure of the status of `srcdoc`